# Update in LINQ with one trip to database?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, ado.net, sql-update

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around when LINQ accesses the database, and how it knows when the optimal time would be.  Mainly, this UPDATE statement seems to make two trips to the database.  But it shouldn't -- there seems to be no "update" equivalent in LINQ short of querying for a row, updating it, and then saving that change.  In basic SQL, I should be able to UPDATE WHERE in one fell swoop.

```
var query = from u in db.users where u.id == 1 select u;
foreach (user u in query)
{
   u.name = "JOE";
}
db.Save();
```

I get the magic of Save.  It allows me to make multiple changes before committing them.  But there still seems to be the initial query for the rows.

Thoughts?  Ideas?

**EDIT**

Now tested, I can confirm that it does in fact go to the database twice.  There must be a better way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `id` is the primary key, you can use:

```
var u = new user { id = 1 };
db.users.Attach(u);
u.name = "JOE";
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Attach doesn't make a trip to the database to figure out which row is being attached?

Comment: No, it doesn't need to. It knows you're referring to the `user` with an `id` of `1`. You (obviously) can't read any other properties from the object, since they haven't been fetched from the database. But any changes you make will be applied through an `UPDATE` command.

Comment: That's great.  Is there a local that I can check with a breakpoint to see what the SQL query actually is?

Comment: If you create a timestamp column and set `user { id = 1, timetamp = savedTimestamp, };` you will get offline concurrency check too.

Comment: @CarlBenson, you can type `myDbContext.Log = Console.Out;` to have each linq2sql-generated SQL query printed to the output window in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at one of custom Linq extensions, like this one http://www.aneyfamily.com/terryandann/post/2008/04/Batch-Updates-and-Deletes-with-LINQ-to-SQL.aspx. You have `DeleteBatch` and `UpdateBatch` methods there. In particular, the `UpdateBatch` takes the condition and the updating expression and executes as one SQL query.